# Why is my procedure producing null result?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have simply created procedure which take 2 inputs and give 2 outputs. 
When I run query separately it gives me proper output, But If I will try to call procedure It produce me `null` result

while calling Query:

```
SELECT field1, field2 
        INTO @var1, @var2
        FROM MyTable ID=? and Name=?
```

and then :

```
select  @var1, @var2;
```

But If I combine the same code in procedure it will give `null` for both fields.

Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `My_Proc`(
    IN `ID` INT,
    IN `Name` VARCHAR(20)
    -- OUT `result` INT,
    -- OUT `result1` INT
)
BEGIN

 set @var1 = 0;
 set @var2 = 0;

    set @query := CONCAT("SELECT
                      field1, field2 
             INTO @var1, @var2
                      FROM MyTable ID=? and Name=?");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    Execute stmt USING @Id,@Name;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;

select @var1,@var2;


END
```

I tried to call `select @var1,@var2;` outside procedure but it also give null fields.

---

I am working in Mysql Workbench 6.0

Comment: remove single quotes in your dynamic query from field1 and field2 and use where clause before id =?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal, quotes where not in actual query, I added by mistake while creating demo code.

Comment: look below at my answer

Answer (score 1):

you have some mistakes in your procedure thats have been removed below..........have a look

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `My_Proc`(
    IN `ID` INT,
    IN `Name` VARCHAR(20)
    -- OUT `result` INT,
    -- OUT `result1` INT
)
BEGIN

 set @var1 = 0;
 set @var2 = 0;

    set @query := CONCAT("SELECT
                      field1,field2 
             INTO @var1, @var2
                      FROM MyTable where ID=? and Name=?");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    Execute stmt USING @Id,@Name;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt ;

select @var1,@var2;


END
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me change in original Proc and check.

Comment: Again,  'from' was just missed in Demo. I correct tiny mistakes, Still no result!

Comment: Need to set @id,@name

Comment: @P.Salmon, also tried that way, but still it;s null.